# how to add a class method to Mongoid::Criteria?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, mongoid

I want to add a new class method to Mongoid::Criteria, all models can use this method, for example:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  ......
end
```

then I add below code to rails initialize

```
class Mongoid::Criteria
  def use_master
    read(mode: :primary_preferred)
  end
end
```

but it doesn't work:

```
pry(main)> User.use_master
NoMethodError: undefined method `use_master' for User:Class
```

How to add the "use_master" method to model? Any help in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

Read preference can be changed via persistence context:

```
User.with(read: {mode: :primary_preferred}) do
  # ...
end
```

This is explained in more depth in Mongoid manual: https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/master/tutorials/mongoid-persistence/#runtime-persistence-options

Answer (score 0):

I found a good solution:

```
module Mongoid
  module Findable
    def use_master
      read(mode: :primary_preferred)
    end
  end
end
```